# Hyperlink to pdf clicking on picture as part of command

Tags: macros, hyperlink

I have a script with command which takes three parameters. It generates a document with two columns of pictures. I would like to open a pdf which is source of the picture after clicking on the picture.

```
\newenvironment{ShowSubFigure}[3]
{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{#1}
       \href{run:/Path/{#3}}
    \subcaption{ \texttt{#1}}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{#2}
    \subcaption{\texttt{#2}}
\end{subfigure}
}
```

where #1,#2 are names of the image files in my local directory, which also serve as captions for the picture. Until this point my script works.

Now, I would like to click on the picture and hyperlink to the pdf.
#3 is the name of the pdf file.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht!]\section{section_name} \subsection{subsection_name} \begin{ShowSubFigure}{first_image_name, pdf_file_name}{second_image_name}\end{ShowSubFigure}\end{figure*}
```

Comment: As always on this site, you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can just copy and test as is. As example images you can use the images that come with the `mwe` package, see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe

Comment: `\href` requires 2 (mandatory) arguments. 
So use `\href{run:/Path/{#3}}{<some text>}`, on cosider to use only `\url`.